Error downloading a csv from website with get in R
downloadfilename = paste("sec_bhavdata_full_", (format(myDate, "%d%m%Y")), ".csv", sep = "")

myURL = paste("``https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/products/content/``", downloadfilename, sep = "")

GET(myURL, user_agent("Mozilla/5.0"), write_disk(downloadfilename))

**Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :
Recv failure: Connection was reset**

is the response received in using GET with the url.
URL - "https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/products/content/sec_bhavdata_full_24092024.csv"

Is it possible to download the csv file Using library(httr) ?
How can I resolve this problem?

Empty reply from server - is the response now.

For this particular site you also need to set accept-language header:
library(httr)

headers = c(
  `accept-language` = "en-GB,en;q=0.8",
  `user-agent` = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/129.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
)
res <- httr::GET(url = "https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/products/content/sec_bhavdata_full_24092024.csv", httr::add_headers(.headers=headers))
http_status(res) |> str()
#> List of 3
#>  $ category: chr "Success"
#>  $ reason  : chr "OK"
#>  $ message : chr "Success: (200) OK"
headers(res) |> str()
#> List of 15
#>  $ content-security-policy  : chr "frame-ancestors self"
#>  $ accept-ranges            : chr "bytes"
#>  $ etag                     : chr "W/\"310024-1727202324779\""
#>  $ last-modified            : chr "Tue, 24 Sep 2024 18:25:24 GMT"
#>  $ content-type             : chr "text/csv"
#>  $ x-frame-options          : chr "SAMEORIGIN"
#>  $ vary                     : chr "Accept-Encoding"
#>  $ content-encoding         : chr "gzip"
#>  $ date                     : chr "Wed, 25 Sep 2024 13:34:35 GMT"
#>  $ transfer-encoding        : chr "chunked"
#>  $ connection               : chr "keep-alive"
#>  $ connection               : chr "Transfer-Encoding"
#>  $ strict-transport-security: chr "max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains ; preload"
#>  $ set-cookie               : chr "_abck=B9ED31EBC7822853F135D8548F2857EC~-1~YAAQ0wFJF5qFSBOSAQAAog1kKQxvr0WB21IofVGoFHbw1sCOr/fT4aVi9jPc5aE6AumYl"| __truncated__
#>  $ set-cookie               : chr "bm_sz=6ECC051817F8E170DAB522EFE0D86B49~YAAQ0wFJF5uFSBOSAQAAog1kKRlF9QWaQykTQwCIjFkjJTf0uIUz+cb2S3aOacmFPul6mIB4"| __truncated__
#>  - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "insensitive" "list"
content(res)
#> No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
#> Rows: 2701 Columns: 15
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: ","
#> chr  (5): SYMBOL, SERIES, DATE1, DELIV_QTY, DELIV_PER
#> dbl (10): PREV_CLOSE, OPEN_PRICE, HIGH_PRICE, LOW_PRICE, LAST_PRICE, CLOSE_P...
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
#> # A tibble: 2,701 × 15
#>    SYMBOL     SERIES DATE1 PREV_CLOSE OPEN_PRICE HIGH_PRICE LOW_PRICE LAST_PRICE
#>    <chr>      <chr>  <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1 1018GS2026 GS     24-S…      112.       118.       118.      112.       112  
#>  2 20MICRONS  EQ     24-S…      299.       301        310       300        302. 
#>  3 21STCENMGM BE     24-S…      118.       116.       116.      116.       116. 
#>  4 360ONE     EQ     24-S…     1074       1074       1088      1065.      1080. 
#>  5 3IINFOLTD  EQ     24-S…       32.7       32.9       32.9      32.3       32.5
#>  6 3MINDIA    EQ     24-S…    35489      35600      35878     35051.     35200  
#>  7 3PLAND     BE     24-S…       40.2       39.5       40        38.2       39.2
#>  8 574GS2026  GS     24-S…      100         98.9       99.9      98.9       99.9
#>  9 5PAISA     EQ     24-S…      559.       570        570       541.       554  
#> 10 63MOONS    EQ     24-S…      405.       406.       416       401        409  
#> # ℹ 2,691 more rows
#> # ℹ 7 more variables: CLOSE_PRICE <dbl>, AVG_PRICE <dbl>, TTL_TRD_QNTY <dbl>,
#> #   TURNOVER_LACS <dbl>, NO_OF_TRADES <dbl>, DELIV_QTY <chr>, DELIV_PER <chr>

Created on 2024-09-25 with reprex v2.1.1

Downloading the csv file efficiently. But why this is to be added? And also we have to add this headers in other case where the download is not occurring?

It's site-spcific, not too common but not something unseen either. Could be intentional to block bots and other automated tools.  You can start with the request made by you brwoser, convert it to R /  httr / htrr2 for example with  https://curlconverter.com/r/  and test what headers are required and what are optional.

Yes it was meant to stop automated downloads. Manual downloads are working fine.

Although the question explicitly asks for {httr}-solutions, I would like to add that base R is capable of:
i="https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/products/content/sec_bhavdata_full_24092024.csv"
download.file(url=i, 
              destfile=basename(i), 
              headers=c("User-Agent"="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/129.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")) 

giving
> read.csv(basename(i)) |> head() |> str()
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ SYMBOL       : chr  "1018GS2026" "20MICRONS" "21STCENMGM" "360ONE" ...
 $ SERIES       : chr  " GS" " EQ" " BE" " EQ" ...
 $ DATE1        : chr  " 24-Sep-2024" " 24-Sep-2024" " 24-Sep-2024" " 24-Sep-2024" ...
 $ PREV_CLOSE   : num  112.1 299.1 118.4 1074 32.7 ...
 $ OPEN_PRICE   : num  117.7 301 116 1074 32.9 ...
 $ HIGH_PRICE   : num  117.7 310 116 1088 32.9 ...
 $ LOW_PRICE    : num  111.9 300 116 1065.2 32.3 ...
 $ LAST_PRICE   : num  112 301.6 116 1080.2 32.5 ...
 $ CLOSE_PRICE  : num  112 300.7 116 1078.5 32.5 ...
 $ AVG_PRICE    : num  112 304.5 116 1073.2 32.6 ...
 $ TTL_TRD_QNTY : int  2999 188515 2202 288547 410829 2832
 $ TURNOVER_LACS: num  3.36 574.1 2.55 3096.57 133.98 ...
 $ NO_OF_TRADES : int  17 6376 47 28969 3366 1771
 $ DELIV_QTY    : chr  " 2999" " 56267" " -" " 199216" ...
 $ DELIV_PER    : chr  " 100.00" " 29.85" " -" " 69.04" ...

System information added as per user @margusl's comment: macOS Sonoma 14.6.1

This is likely system-dependant, on my W11 / R4.4.1 / libcurl 0.6.0 setup download.file() times out in 60 seconds even if I set exact same headers as for httr.

@margusl, might be. download.file() has several system-dependant functionalities. I will add in the information, thank you.
